# Loan System Calculator

Tags: c++11

I would really like feedback on this Loan System Calculator. My goal is to get better at OOP design and would like to know if I've done a good job in making this scenario OOP? Could I have structured it better? Should I have separated each loan type as a separate class using inheritance? I would like to know what I've done well too! Thanks to anyone who spends their time to review it.
[image]
// Loan System.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class Customer {
private:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_age;
    double m_salary;
    double m_takeOutLoan;
    std::string m_loanType;
    int m_loanLength;
public:
    Customer():m_name("No name"), m_age(0), m_salary(0), m_takeOutLoan(0), m_loanType("No loan name specified"),m_loanLength(0){}
    
    void SetName(std::string name) { m_name = name; }
    void SetAge(int age) { m_age = age; }
    void SetSalary(double salary) { m_salary = salary; }

    std::string GetName() const { return m_name; }
    int GetAge() const { return m_age; }
    double GetSalary() const { return m_salary; }

    void SetTakeOutLoan(double takeOutLoan) { m_takeOutLoan = takeOutLoan; }
    double GetTakeOutLoan() const { return m_takeOutLoan; }

    std::string GetLoanType() const { return m_loanType; }

    void SetLoanLength(int loanLength) { m_loanLength = loanLength; }
    int GetLoanLength()const { return m_loanLength; }

    void SetLoanType(std::string&& loanType) { m_loanType = loanType; }
};

class Loan {
private:
    std::string m_loanType;
    std::string m_loanLength;
    double m_APR;
    double m_maximumLoan;
public:
    int m_loanPeriod;
    Loan(std::string loanType, std::string loanLength, double APR, double maximumLoan, int loanPeriod)
        :m_loanType(loanType), m_loanLength(loanLength), 
        m_APR(APR), m_maximumLoan(maximumLoan), m_loanPeriod(loanPeriod)  {
    }

    std::string GetLoanType()const { return m_loanType; }
    std::string GetLoanLength()const { return m_loanLength; }
    double GetAPR()const { return m_APR; }
    double GetMaximumLoan() const { return m_maximumLoan; }

    void DisplayLoan() const {

        std::cout << "Loan Type: " << m_loanType << "\n";
        std::cout << "Loan Length: " << m_loanLength << "\n";
        std::cout << "APR: " << m_APR * 100 << "%\n";
        std::cout << "Maximum Loan: " << m_maximumLoan <<  "\n";
    }
    int ChoosePaybackPeriod(Customer& customer)  {
        int PaybackPeriod = 0;
        std::cout << "How long do you wish to pay back your loan?: ";
        std::cin >> PaybackPeriod;
        if (PaybackPeriod > 0 && PaybackPeriod <= m_loanPeriod)
        {
            return PaybackPeriod;
        }

        return 0;
    }
};
class LongTerm : public Loan {
private:
public:
    LongTerm():Loan("Standard", "3-5 Years", 0.049, 40000, 5){} 
};

class ShortTerm : public Loan
{
private:
public:
    ShortTerm() :Loan("Standard", "1-2 Years", 0.039, 12000, 2) {}
};
class Emergency : public Loan
{
private:
public:
    Emergency() :Loan("Short", "1-6 Months", 0.299, 3000, 6) {}
};

class LoanSystem 
{
private:
    bool ChooseTakeOutLoan(Customer &customer, double maximumTakeOutLoan)
    {
        double requestAmount = 0;
        std::cout << "How much of " << maximumTakeOutLoan << " do you want to take out?: ";
        std::cin >> requestAmount;
        if (requestAmount > 0 && requestAmount <= maximumTakeOutLoan) {
            customer.SetTakeOutLoan(requestAmount);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

public:
    //Check if they are eligible
    bool isQualified(const Customer &customer) {
        const double boundary = 12000;
        if (customer.GetSalary() < boundary || customer.GetAge() < 18) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    void OverallCost(Customer &customer, Loan *loan) {

        std::cout << "Loan: " << customer.GetLoanType() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Amount: " << customer.GetTakeOutLoan() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Time financed: " << customer.GetLoanLength() << " year(s)\n";
        std::cout << "APR for one year " << loan->GetAPR() * customer.GetTakeOutLoan() << "\n";
        std::cout << "APR for time required " << (loan->GetAPR() * 2) * customer.GetTakeOutLoan() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Total payable " << customer.GetTakeOutLoan() + (customer.GetTakeOutLoan() * (loan->GetAPR() * 2)) << "\n";
    }
    void calculateLoanType(Customer &customer) 
    {
        double maximumTakeOutLoan = 0;
        int paybackPeriod = 0;
        double APR = 0;
        if (customer.GetAge() > 21 && customer.GetSalary() >= 24000) {
            LongTerm longTerm;
            longTerm.DisplayLoan();

            customer.SetLoanType(longTerm.GetLoanType());
            ChooseTakeOutLoan(customer, longTerm.GetMaximumLoan());
            customer.SetLoanLength(longTerm.ChoosePaybackPeriod(customer));
            OverallCost(customer, &longTerm);
        }
        else if (customer.GetAge() > 18 && customer.GetSalary() >= 21000) {
            ShortTerm shortTerm;          
            shortTerm.DisplayLoan();

            customer.SetLoanType(shortTerm.GetLoanType());       
            ChooseTakeOutLoan(customer, shortTerm.GetMaximumLoan());
            customer.SetLoanLength(shortTerm.ChoosePaybackPeriod(customer));
            OverallCost(customer, &shortTerm);
        }
        else if (customer.GetAge() > 18 && customer.GetSalary() >= 12000) {
            Emergency emergency;        
            emergency.DisplayLoan();

            customer.SetLoanType(emergency.GetLoanType());
            ChooseTakeOutLoan(customer, emergency.GetMaximumLoan());
         
            customer.SetLoanLength(emergency.ChoosePaybackPeriod(customer));
            OverallCost(customer, &emergency);
        }
    }
};

void GetCustomerInformation(Customer &customer) {
    std::string name = "";
    int age = 0;
    double salary = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, name);
    customer.SetName(name);

    std::cout << "Enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> age;
    customer.SetAge(age);

    std::cout << "Enter your salary: ";
    std::cin >> salary;
    customer.SetSalary(salary);
}

int main()
{
    LoanSystem loanSystem;
    Customer customer;
   
    GetCustomerInformation(customer);

    std::cout << "Your name is: " << customer.GetName() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Your age is: " << customer.GetAge() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Your salary is: " << customer.GetSalary() << "\n";

    std::cout << "Is " << customer.GetName() << " eligible for a loan?: ";
    
    if (loanSystem.isQualified(customer))
    {
        std::cout << customer.GetName() << " is eligible!\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << customer.GetName() << " isn't eligible!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    loanSystem.calculateLoanType(customer);
    std::cout << "The customer has decided to take out: " << customer.GetTakeOutLoan() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `Loan` should be pure abstract interface, you can derive from it

Comment: I thought this actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that `Loan` be a pure abstract interface. `Loan` is also cluttered with information that deserve it own class. We name that class `LoanInformation`. It can be defined as follow.

```
class LoanInformation
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LoanInformation loanInfo);
    private:
        std::string m_LoanType;
        std::string m_LoanLength;
        double m_APR;
        double m_maximumLoan;
    public:
        LoanInformation(const std::string& type, const std::string&  loanLength, double APR, double maximumLoan)
        :   m_LoanType{type}, m_LoanLength{loanLength}, m_APR{APR}, m_maximumLoan{maximumLoan} {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LoanInformation loanInfo)
{
    os << "Loan Type: " << loanInfo.m_LoanType << "\n";
    os << "Loan Length: " << loanInfo.m_LoanLength << "\n";
    os << "APR: " << loanInfo.m_APR * 100 << "%\n";
    os << "Maximum Loan: " << loanInfo.m_maximumLoan <<  "\n";

    return os;
}
```

Now we can define a Loan like this

```
class Loan 
{
    private:
        LoanInformation m_loanInfo;
        int m_ageCriteria;
        int m_salaryCriteria;
    public:
        Loan(const LoanInformation& loanInfo, int ageCriteria, int salaryCriteria) 
            : m_loanInfo{loanInfo}, m_ageCriteria{ageCriteria}, m_salaryCriteria{salaryCriteria} { };
        void displayLoan() 
        {
            std::cout << m_loanInfo;
        }
        int ageCriteria() const { return m_ageCriteria; }
        int salaryCriteria() const { return m_salaryCriteria; }
        virtual bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const = 0;
         virtual ~Loan(){}
};
```

All classes that derive from `Loan` must define `isQualified`. This gives us a good implementation inheritance. Adding more types that derives from `Loan` cannot be more easier.

```
class ShortTermLoan : public Loan
{
    public:
        ShortTermLoan(const LoanInformation& loanInfo, int ageCriteria, int salaryCriteria) 
            : Loan(loanInfo, ageCriteria, salaryCriteria) {}
        bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const
        {
            return (customer.age() > ageCriteria() && customer.salary() >= salaryCriteria());
        }
        virtual ~ShortTermLoan(){}
};

class LongTermLoan : public Loan
{
    public:
        LongTermLoan(const LoanInformation& loanInfo, int ageCriteria, int salaryCriteria) 
            : Loan(loanInfo, ageCriteria, salaryCriteria){}
        bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const
        {
            return (customer.age() > ageCriteria() && customer.salary() >= salaryCriteria());
        }
        virtual ~LongTermLoan(){}
};

class EmergencyLoan : public Loan
{
    public:
        EmergencyLoan(const LoanInformation& loanInfo, int ageCriteria, int salaryCriteria) 
            : Loan(loanInfo, ageCriteria, salaryCriteria){}
        bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const
        {
            return (customer.age() > ageCriteria() && customer.salary() >= salaryCriteria());
        }
        virtual ~EmergencyLoan()
};
```

All classes that derives from `Loan` have its notion of what `isQualified` means. [EDIT]  We made `isQualified` a virtual function because users that might want to derive from our `Loan` class may have a different method of checking for customer eligibility which is not defined in the base class.

Though passing a `customer` as a parameter looks a little sluggish, it is fine for this situation. We can define a simple `Customer` class like this

```
class Customer
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Customer& customer);
    private:
        int m_age; // This are made private because they might need to be validated
        double m_salary;
    public:
        Customer(const std::string& name, int age, double salary)
            : m_age{age}, m_salary{salary}, m_name{name} {}
        std::string m_name; // No need to check names
        int age() const { return m_age; }
        double salary() const { return m_salary; }
    // more method-function
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Customer& customer)
{
    os << "Name: " << customer.m_name << '\n';
    os << "Age: " << customer.m_age << '\n';
    os << "Salary: " << customer.m_salary << '\n';

    return os;
}
```

This class is simple enough.
We create three instances of `LoanInformation`

```
LoanInformation longLoanInfo{"Standard", "3-5 years", 0.049, 40000};
LoanInformation shortLoanInfo{"Standard", "3-5 years", 0.039, 12000};
LoanInformation emergencyLoanInfo{"Short", "1-6 months", 0.299, 3000};
```

We can also construct it from a file.

We initialize our loans based on their basic information and create an `std::vector` to store them. We can create our customer instance easily and check the loan the customer is eligible for

```
ShortTermLoan shortTerm{shortLoanInfo, 18, 21000};
LongTermLoan longTern{longLoanInfo, 21, 24000};
EmergencyLoan emergency{emergencyLoanInfo, 18, 12000};
std::vector<Loan*> loans{&shortTerm, &longTern, &emergency};

Customer customer{"Samuel", 19, 20000};
checkCustomerEligibilty(customer, loans);
```

`checkCustomerEligibilty` becomes so much easy and can be done polymorphically, if we derive classes from `Loan`, there would be no problem.

```
void checkCustomerEligibilty(Customer& customer, std::vector<Loan*> loans)
{
    for(auto loan : loans)
    {
        if(loan->isQualified(customer))
        {
            std::cout << customer.m_name << " is Qualified for: \n";
            loan->displayLoan();
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I am going to painstakingly go through everything you’ve suggested, understand it then implement it into my program! I’ll be sure to have questions as I usually do.

Comment: Hi, I've posted my updated code as an answer. Could you have a look at it for me please? I created a new class called "Bank". Could you give me feedback on it? Have I implemented it correctly? I've based it principally off your suggestions. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253394/214082

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Bank {
private:
    double m_loanAmount;
    int m_paybackPeriod;
public:
    Bank() :m_loanAmount{0}, m_paybackPeriod{0} {}

    double loanAmount() const { return m_loanAmount; }
    void setLoanAmount(double loanAmount) { m_loanAmount = loanAmount; }

    void setPaybackPeriod(int paybackPeriod) { m_paybackPeriod = paybackPeriod; }
    double paybackPeriod()const { return m_paybackPeriod; }
};
class Customer {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Customer& customer);
private:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_age;
    double m_salary;
public:
    Bank account;
    Customer(std::string name = "No name", int age = 0, double salary = 0):m_name(name), m_age(age), m_salary(salary){}
    std::string GetName() const { return m_name; }
    int GetAge() const { return m_age; }

    void SetName(std::string name) { m_name = name; }
    void SetAge(int age) { m_age = age; }

    double GetSalary() const { return m_salary; }
    void SetSalary(double salary) { m_salary = salary; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Customer& customer) 
{
    os << "Name: " << customer.m_name << "\n";
    os << "Age: " << customer.m_age << "\n";
    os << "Salary: " << customer.m_salary << "\n";
    return os;
}
class LoanInformation 
{
    friend std::ostream&operator<<(std::ostream& os, LoanInformation loanInfo);
private:
    std::string m_loan;
    std::string m_loanType;
    std::string m_loanLength;
    double m_APR;
    double m_maximumLoan;
    int m_maxLoanLength;
public:
    double maximumLoan()const { return m_maximumLoan; }
    double APR() const { return m_APR; }
    int maxLoanLength() const { return m_maxLoanLength; }
    LoanInformation(std::string loan, const std::string &type, const std::string&loanLength, double APR, double maximumLoan, int maxLoanPeriod)
        :m_loan{ loan }, m_loanType{ type }, m_loanLength{ loanLength }, m_APR{ APR }, m_maximumLoan{ maximumLoan }, m_maxLoanLength{ maxLoanPeriod }{}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LoanInformation loanInfo) {
    os << loanInfo.m_loan << "\n";
    os << "Loan Type: " << loanInfo.m_loanType << "\n";
    os << "Loan Length: " << loanInfo.m_loanLength << "\n";
    os << "APR: " << loanInfo.m_APR * 100 << "%\n";
    os << "Maximum Loan: " << loanInfo.m_maximumLoan << "\n";
    return os;
}

class Loan {
private:
    
    int m_ageCriteria;
    double m_salaryCriteria;
public:
    LoanInformation m_loanInfo;
    void displayLoan() 
    {
        std::cout << m_loanInfo;
    }
    Loan(const LoanInformation &loanInfo, int ageCriteria, double salaryCriteria)
        :m_loanInfo{ loanInfo }, m_ageCriteria{ ageCriteria }, m_salaryCriteria{salaryCriteria}
    {}

    int ageCriteria()const { return m_ageCriteria; }
    double salaryCriteria()const { return m_salaryCriteria; }
    virtual bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const = 0;
    virtual ~Loan() {}
};
class ShortTermLoan : public Loan
{
private:
public:
    ShortTermLoan(const LoanInformation &loanInfo, int ageCriteria, double salaryCritieria)
        :Loan{loanInfo, ageCriteria, salaryCritieria} {}
    virtual bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const override {
        return (customer.GetAge() > ageCriteria() && customer.GetSalary() >= salaryCriteria());
    }
    virtual ~ShortTermLoan() = default;

};
class LongTermLoan : public Loan {
private:
public:
    LongTermLoan(const LoanInformation& loanInfo, int ageCriteria, double salaryCriteria)
        :Loan{ loanInfo, ageCriteria, salaryCriteria } {}
    virtual bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const override {
        return (customer.GetAge() > ageCriteria() && customer.GetSalary() >= salaryCriteria());
    }
    virtual ~LongTermLoan() = default;
};


class EmergencyLoan : public Loan
{
private:
public:
    EmergencyLoan(const LoanInformation& loanInfo, int ageCriteria, double salaryCriteria)
        :Loan{ loanInfo, ageCriteria, salaryCriteria } {}
    virtual bool isQualified(const Customer& customer) const override {
        return (customer.GetAge() > ageCriteria() && customer.GetSalary() >= salaryCriteria());
    }
    virtual ~EmergencyLoan() = default;

};

class LoanSystem 
{
    std::vector<Loan*>availableLoans;
private:
    bool ChoosePaybackPeriod(Customer& customer, Loan*loan) {
        int PaybackPeriod = 0;
        std::cout << "How long do you wish to pay back your loan?: ";
        std::cin >> PaybackPeriod;
        if (PaybackPeriod > 0 && PaybackPeriod <= loan->m_loanInfo.maxLoanLength())
        {
            customer.account.setPaybackPeriod(PaybackPeriod);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    bool ChooseTakeOutLoan(Customer &customer, double maximumTakeOutLoan)
    {
        double requestAmount = 0;
        std::cout << "How much of " << maximumTakeOutLoan << " do you want to take out?: ";
        std::cin >> requestAmount;
        if (requestAmount > 0 && requestAmount <= maximumTakeOutLoan) {
            customer.account.setLoanAmount(requestAmount);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

public:
    void checkCustomerEligibility(Customer& customer, std::vector<Loan*>&loans) {
        
        for (auto& loan : loans) 
        {
            if (loan->isQualified(customer)) 
            {             
                availableLoans.push_back(loan);            
            }           
        }
    }
    void DisplayAvailableLoans(Customer &customer) const {
        int countItems = 1;
        std::cout << customer.GetName() << " is qualified for. . . \n\n";
        for (auto& loan : availableLoans) {
            std::cout << countItems++ << ". ";
            loan->displayLoan();
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    void specifyAmount(Customer &customer) {

    }
    void chooseLoanPlan(Customer &customer, std::vector<Loan*>&loans) {
        std::size_t index = 0;
        checkCustomerEligibility(customer, loans);
        try 
        {
            DisplayAvailableLoans(customer);
            std::cout << "Choose loan type (e.g. 1): ";
            std::cin >> index;           
            ChooseTakeOutLoan(customer, availableLoans.at(index - 1)->m_loanInfo.maximumLoan());
            ChoosePaybackPeriod(customer, availableLoans.at(index - 1));
            OverallCost(customer, availableLoans.at(index - 1));
        }
        catch (...) 
        {
            std::cout << "Your input is invalid!\n";
        }
    }
    void OverallCost(Customer &customer, Loan *loan) {

        loan->displayLoan();     
        std::cout << "Amount: " << customer.account.loanAmount() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Time financed: " << customer.account.paybackPeriod() << " year(s)\n";
        std::cout << "APR for one year " << loan->m_loanInfo.APR() * customer.account.loanAmount() << "\n";
        std::cout << "APR for time required " << (loan->m_loanInfo.APR() * 2) * customer.account.loanAmount() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Total payable " << customer.account.loanAmount() + (customer.account.loanAmount() * (loan->m_loanInfo.APR() * 2)) << "\n";
    }
   
};

void GetCustomerInformation(Customer &customer) {
    std::string name = "";
    int age = 0;
    double salary = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, name);
    customer.SetName(name);

    std::cout << "Enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> age;
    customer.SetAge(age);

    std::cout << "Enter your salary: ";
    std::cin >> salary;
    customer.SetSalary(salary);
}


int main()
{
    LoanSystem loanSystem;
    LoanInformation longLoanInfo{ "Long Term Loan","Standard", "3-5 years", 0.049, 40000,5 };
    LoanInformation shortLoanInfo{ "Short Term Loan", "Standard", "3-5 years", 0.039, 12000,2 };
    LoanInformation emergencyLoanInfo{ "Emergency Loan", "Short", "1-6 months", 0.299, 3000, 6};

    ShortTermLoan shortTerm{ shortLoanInfo, 18, 21000 };
    LongTermLoan longTerm{ longLoanInfo, 21, 24000 };
    EmergencyLoan emergency{ emergencyLoanInfo, 18, 12000 };

    std::vector<Loan*> loans{ &shortTerm, &longTerm, &emergency };
    
    Customer customer("Jack Kimmins", 24, 12000);
    
    //GetCustomerInformation(customer);
    //loanSystem.checkCustomerEligibility(customer, loans);
    loanSystem.chooseLoanPlan(customer, loans);
    std::cout << "Take out loan: " << customer.account.loanAmount();
    
}
```

Comment: There are lots of improvement, I personally would not have a `bank` or `LoanSystem` class. Make them free functions, maybe hidden in a namespace. Secondly, your `notion` of a bank is just not right,  I would expect a bank to have `Accounts`, `Customers`

Comment: Can you have a default customer with no names and an age of 0? You would also want to avoid setters and getters also. You should have a concrete reasoning of providing a default.

Comment: I was experimenting with default values there! Just ignore that haha. Ok, I’ll have them as free functions.  One of the things I was really puzzling over was whereabouts do I store the chosen payback period variable? I understand about the bank, even when I creating it I was questioning it. Where do I store the bank variables then? Do they belong to the customer?

Comment: It can be part of the namespace.

Comment: Part of the namespace?

Comment: Check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161199/what-exactly-is-a-namespace-and-why-is-it-necessary/32161640)

Comment: I understand about namespaces, however, why should I put the time period e.g. two years which the user chooses and store it in a namespace? Isn’t storing it in the customer class better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117221/discussion-between-george-austin-bradley-and-theprogrammer).